# Av Receiver or other device that can Miracast to a projector?

Tags: wireless, amplifiers

I am looking at the [ZTE Spro 2 projector](https://www.zteusa.com/media/wysiwyg/spro2-att/ZTE_Spro_2_AT_T_User_Manual_English_-_PDF_-_18.8MB_.pdf).

This is an android projector that can accept a Miracast broadcast from another device such as a mobile phone.

Are there any AV receivers/hi-fis or other device that is not a PC, that can Miracast to this projector? I am thinking I could plug things like an XBox and Sky into this device and then wirelessly cast this to the projector?

I have seen some Miracast dongles, but they seem to work in the wrong direction for what I want.

Comment: I have found this: https://www.epson.co.uk/gb/en/viewcon/corporatesite/products/consumables/overview/13905

But I am not sure if it can send to all miracast devices or just the epson glasses.

I have put this as a comment as it is useful. It should be an answer in my opinion.

Comment: I tried the epson and it did not work, some zte spro2 have miracast and some of them have a different casting system. The one I currently have had this different casting system. So still not sure if this device works with a zte spro2 that has normal miracast.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few such devices:

- [Mirabox Projection Gateway](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/HDMI-VGA-Wireless-Mirroring-Prejection-Gateway-For-Airplay-Miracast-Windows-Widi-Wifi-Presentation-Mirrorlink-Wireless-Mirroring/32812513019.html)
- [Monoprice Blackbird 4K 4x4 HDMI Matrix Extender with 4 Receivers, PoC, IR, EDID](https://www.monoprice.com/product?c_id=101&cp_id=10105&cs_id=1011012&p_id=21905&seq=1&format=2)
- [Monoprice BitPath AV 4K HDMI Wireless Transmitter & Receiver Kit, 200m](https://www.monoprice.com/product?c_id=101&cp_id=10105&cs_id=1011012&p_id=16223&seq=1&format=2)